# Why does Github desktop is showing an error?

Tags: github, desktop

I have been working on my front end coding project and I tried updating my Github origin. However, there's an error when I tried to push origin. I uninstalled and reinstalled Github desktop but it seems like it's showing the same error. Could someone help me figure this out? Please let me know and thank you so much!

[image: github error message]

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error message was followed in 2017 by [`desktop/desktop` issue 2623](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2623)

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\Alca\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.8.0\resources\app\static\ask-pass-trampoline.bat'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

[Solution](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2623#issuecomment-496018777):

> Just wanted to comment that a previous installation of Miniconda had created a AutoRun key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\`
>
> Deleting the key fixed this problem for me.

But there is also an [related issue involving Git LFS](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3752#issuecomment-362160566). If you don't have activated LFS though, it should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi VonC, thank you for your detailed input. I just wanted to ask you how can I access HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\? And where can I check if I have activated the LFS or not? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @SerenaHendrickson It is in regedit, the registry editor of Windows: https://www.lifewire.com/hkey-current-user-2625901

Comment: I found the registry editor and I found all the files except for the command processor. Where else could I go to check if there is an issue?

Comment: @SerenaHendrickson Check at least if you have the latest version of GitHub Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem minutes ago.

The error message was similar with you. The message was containing path: "C:\Users\[myusername]\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.6.0\resources\app\static\ask-pass-trampoline.bat"

Try this:

```
1. Ctrl+R 

2. Type regedit 

3. Go to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

And check Autorun(String value) is set or not

If the Autorun has any value, remove the value and try Github desktop.
Otherwise, idk.

My Github desktop(2.6.0) worked with this solution.

I think the problem was caused by myself or other program who did manipulated the registry long ago.